# Grouping icons into folders

Tags: slingshot

I'm looking for a way to group several icons into one folder. For example: DisplayCAL is a set of six utilities I'd like very much to group instead of having them spread in alphabetical order.

eOs Juno

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [AppEditor](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/) seems to provide the ability to change a category assignment of an app. You could use it to put all in the same category.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to create a folder of icons in the application menu upto now. There's a piece of software called `gnome-appfolders-manager` which is not maintained any more so, I suggest not to use that.

However, In the Application menu there is a option to view them by category. But this doesn't allow you to create your own category or group of apps.